# AWS DynamoDB permissions - getting error when user queries database

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Amazon Web Services to provide my users access my DynamoDB table. I am using Cognito for log in, and it seems to work. I have create the database and the policy to query my database. I have the code in the app, I have a user group, I have the database (write to it fine), I have the policy written. AWS is still giving me an access error.

[image]

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't set your permissions properly for the table to allow GET

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer - I really appreciate it! I have the permissions and that actually seems to be OK - my issue now may be my code. I changed the query code (hashKeyAttribute) and got a the error that I coded in as my error message so I think that indicates that I can access the database but need better code ... do you know of / have any good query code examples?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the IAM console and attach appropriate policies for doing operations like getItem on your table. You need to attach a policy for the unauth / auth role created by Cognito Identity Pool. For a similar working app, you can use AWS Mobile Hub which will create policies for you and give a sample app which demonstrates using the queries on a table.

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: thanks for your answer - I really appreciate it! I have the permissions and that actually seems to be OK - my issue now may be my code. I changed the query code (hashKeyAttribute) and got a the error that I coded in as my error message so I think that indicates that I can access the database but need better code ... do you know of / have any good query code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would recommend to do to fix the problem:

First in the `Overview` tab of your DynamoDB table, copy the `Amazon Resource Name (ARN)` it should look something like:

```
arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:227509******:table/TableName
```

After that go to your IAM console and click on `Roles` off to the left. Once in the Roles section click on the UnAuth_Role for the app associated with your table. Should look like:

```
Cognito_AppNameUnauth_Role
```

Once here, click on Create Role Policy - then select Custom Policy - then click Select.

- Create a name for your policy

Copy this code but edit it with your ARN:

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:GetItem",
            "dynamodb:Scan",
            "dynamodb:Query",
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:227509******:table/TableName",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:227509******:table/TableName/index/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Add more permissions if you need to like :

```
"dynamodb:DeleteItem",
"dynamodb:PutItem",
"dynamodb:UpdateItem",
"dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
```

I can't guarantee that will fix the problem. But it's a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue. I have successfully authenticated via Cognito UserPool, verified policy was set up, ran into error code 6 as you did above. Found that if I changed user table permissions from "Private" to "Public", although not desirable, allowed me to read/write from table.

[DynamoDB Table Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWshs.png)

The "Condition" clause below is added when you select "Private" instead of "Public" through the console. I can't find clear documentation on what this means / how to satisfy the condition it's asking for. (If someone understands better feel free to help edit this response!)

```
"Effect":"Allow",
  "Action": [
    "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
    "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
    "dynamodb:GetItem",
    "dynamodb:ListTables",
    "dynamodb:Query"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:dynamodb:...:table/...",
    ...
  ],
"Condition": {
  "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"]
  }
}
```